# How to skip obsolete attribute error on w3validation?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

i have an example of HTML page that contain some tags & attributes that are Deprecate/obsolete in HTML5. like valign, Frameborder, cellspacing etc. but my website showing W3validation error when i have checked it. i am unable to remove that tags so i am doing that after window load remove cellspacing attribute from table. but its show in w3 error. please help

Example link of my HTML code
http://suffitechh.com/pra/w3/index.php

W3validator link 
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fsuffitechh.com%2Fpra%2Fw3%2F

Comment: Use CSS instead of attributes

Comment: What if i cant use CSS. actually in my case i am not Able to remove that attributes from the Tags they are come from Third party and i cant handle that.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not just get rid of all that and use a responsive iframe?**

```
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/aP3TBpWWwJ8' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

You can change the size using the percentage just before the iframe code.

Codepen [Demo](http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/yazggq)

**This method checks clear from where you tested..**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 60%; height:60%; }</style>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/aP3TBpWWwJ8'></iframe></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey johnny, but in my case i cant use the CSS. even i cant remove that attributes. as they are come from a third part module.

Comment: So why not do away with the module and use the straight code? And you should be able to change or create overrides for CSS in most situations.